# Multiple Row Auto Calculation and CheckBox? How to reduce it?

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, checkbox

> ## **What will I add if everytime user is unchecking the checkbox, the ammount will be reduced ? Thanks**

I have a code below :

```
echo '<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="eg_payamt_[]" Value="' . $amount_dueArr[$record_count] . '" size="10"><br>';//display ammountDue (AmmountDue)                   

echo '<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="eg_payamt_[]" Value="' . $TotalArr[$record_count] . '" size="10"><br>';//display outstanding (Total)

<td><input type="checkbox" name="pay[]" value="" /></td>
```

[image]

My question is, how to calculate the total amount inside the textbox everytime user click the checkbox ?

Thanks

can you do like this :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<td><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="eg_payamt_[]" Value="" size="10"><td><br>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="pay[]" value="" onclick="return calculateSum();" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="eg_payamt_[]" Value="" size="10"><td><br>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="pay[]" value="" onclick="return calculateSum();" /></td>
<tr>
<td><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="answer" id="answer" Value="" size="10"><td><br>
</tr>
</table>


<script>
    function calculateSum() {

        var sum = 0;
        //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
       //$("input:text").each(function() {
       $("input[type='text'][name='eg_payamt_[]']").each(function(){ 

            //add only if the value is number
            if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
                sum += parseFloat(this.value);
            }

        });

        //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
        $("#answer").val(sum.toFixed(2));
    }
</script>
```

can you do like this ? is it working ? i m trying now...

complete code :

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.js">
</script>
</head>
<script>
                                    function calculateSum() {

                                        var sum = 0;
                                        //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
                                        //$("input:textbox").each(function() {
                                        //$("input:eg_payamt_[]").each(function() { 
                                        $("input[type='text'][name='eg_payamt_[]']").each(function(){       


                                            //add only if the value is number
                                            if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
                                                sum += parseFloat(this.value);
                                            }

                                        });
                                        //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
                                        $("#answer").html(sum.toFixed(2));
                                    }
                                    </script>


     <form name="payform" method="POST" action="payment.php">
    <H2>Pay Invoices</H2>

        <table border="0"><!--begin of the table-->
            <tr>
               <td><b>Date</b></td>
               <td><b>Invoice</b></td>
               <td><b>Ammount</b></td>
               <td><b>Outstanding</b></td>
               <td><b>Pay</b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="512px" colspan="5"><IMG SRC="rule-black.gif" WIDTH="800" HEIGHT="11"><br></td>
            </tr>

            <?php
                  echo '<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="record" Value="'.$record.'">';
              $amountDueTotal = 0;
           for($record_count=0;$record_count<$record;$record_count++)
                { //loop for record count
                        ?>


            <tr>

               <td> 
                    <?php
                        $strDate = $node_date->nodeValue; //display the date of invoice (Date)
                        echo substr($strDate, -2) . '-' . substr($strDate, -4, 2) . '-' . substr($strDate, 0, 4);
                        //echo $node_date->nodeValue; //display the date of invoice (Date)
                    ?>
               </td>

               <td>
                   <?php
                       //echo $node_inv_no->nodeValue; //display the invoice number (DocumentID)
                       echo '<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="eg_description_[]" Value="' . $invoiceArr[$record_count] . '" size="20"><br>';  //display the invoice number (DocumentID)
                    ?>   
               </td>

               <td>
                    <?php
                       echo '<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="eg_payamt_[]" Value="' . $amount_dueArr[$record_count] . '" size="10"><br>';//display ammountDue (AmmountDue)                   
                       //echo $node_amount_due->nodeValue; //display ammountDue (AmmountDue)
                    ?>   
               </td>

               <td>
                    <?php
                       echo '<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="eg_payamt_[]" Value="' . $TotalArr[$record_count] . '" size="10"><br>';//display outstanding (Total)                   
                       //echo $node_total->nodeValue; //display outstanding (Total)
                    ?>   
               </td>
               <td><input type="checkbox" name="pay[]" value="" onClick="calculateSum()"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td></td>

               <?php
                     $amountDueTotal += $amount_dueArr[$record_count]; //calculate the total ammount due
                       //Hidden fields
                      echo '<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="eg_invoice_[]" Value="'.$invoiceNoArr[$record_count].'">';
                      echo '<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_invage_[]" Value="'.$DateArr[$record_count].'">';
                }//end of the record count loop 

                ?>
            <tr>
               <td>Pay Ammount Not Listed Above</td>
               <td><input type="text" name="UnknownDocumentID" value="Invoice_unknown_docID_data" /></td>
               <!--<td><input type="text" name="Amount_Due_Unknown_Doc_ID" value="amount" size="10"/></td>--><!--Amount Due-->
               <td><input type="text" name="eg_payamt_[]" value="amount" size="10"/></td><!--Total-->
               <td></td>
               <td><input type="checkbox" name="pay[]" value="" onClick="calculateSum()"/></td>
            </tr>

                     <tr>
                        <td width="512px" colspan="5"><IMG SRC="rule-black.gif" WIDTH="800" HEIGHT="11"><br></td>
                     </tr>



               <td>Total ammount to pay</td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>

                <td>
                    <!--<input type="text" name="total" value="<?php //echo $amountDueTotal;?>" />-->
                    <input type="text" name="totalNS" id="answer" value="" />
                    <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="answer" id="answer" Value="" size="10"><br>

                </td>
             </tr>
```

Payment after click, no result :
[image: Payment after clicking checkbox]

Am I writing the right code ?

```
<INPUT TYPE="text" name="answer" id="answer" Value="" size="10">
```

because when I put

```
document.write(sum);
```

****Got the answer :****

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkTotal() {
        document.listForm.total.value = '';
        var sum = 0;
        for (i=0;i<document.listForm.choice.length;i++) {
          if (document.listForm.choice[i].checked) {
            sum = sum + parseInt(document.listForm.choice[i].value);
          }
        }
        document.listForm.total.value = sum;
    }
</script>

<form name="listForm">
<input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="2" onchange="checkTotal()"/>2<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="5" onchange="checkTotal()"/>5<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="10" onchange="checkTotal()"/>10<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="20" onchange="checkTotal()"/>20<br/>
Total: <input type="text" size="2" name="total" value="0"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Read up on basic JavaScript here: http://www.w3schools.com

Comment: I learned a few bad habits from w3schools that haunt me to this day.  Please don't suggest it :(.  I suggest https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide though it will not be as straight to the point as w3schools with doing what you want.  (You're looking for an onclick event binding by the way.)  Oh and for kicks and giggles: http://w3fools.com/

Comment: You can learn javascript with w3schools.com, not in w3fools.com

Comment: I offered an alternative.  I was simply adding w3fools in since they illustrate some of the errors on w3schools.  Was not suggesting that he learn JavaScript there :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's work out on this below code..

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="eg_payamt_[]" Value="" size="10"><br>

<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="eg_payamt_[]" Value="" size="10"><br>

<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="answer" id="answer" Value="" size="10"><br>

<td><input type="checkbox" name="pay[]" value="" onclick="return calculateSum();" /></td>
<script>
    function calculateSum() {

        var sum = 0;
        //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
       //$("input:text").each(function() {
       $("input[type='text'][name='eg_payamt_[]']").each(function(){ 

            //add only if the value is number
            if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
                sum += parseFloat(this.value);
            }

        });

        //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
        $("#answer").val(sum.toFixed(2));
    }
</script>
```

This working fine for me..Check it out.

Thanks.

Comment: I must put the script under the form ?

Comment: have you using this complete code?? OR make any changes ? because for my case its work perfect with result also. Pls check it.

Comment: it works only in the small form but when I put in the big code it doesn't work

Comment: I don't understand, it's working ok in the small test form but when i put in the real code, it is not working ?? anyone has ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

you need to write the function that calculates tha value (let's call is calculateTotalAmout) and then edit the checkbock tag like this

`<input type="checkbox" name="pay[]" value="" onClick="calculateTotalAmout()" />`

Answer (score 1):

Try below code for your task.

Put `calculateSum()` function onClick event of checkbox;

```
<script>
    function calculateSum() {

        var sum = 0;
        //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
        $("input:textbox").each(function() {

            //add only if the value is number
            if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
                sum += parseFloat(this.value);
            }

        });
        //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
        $("#answer").val(sum.toFixed(2));
    }
</script>
```

Thanks.

Comment: ("input:textbox") = NAME="eg_payamt_[]", how can i define it ?

Comment: @user1063526 : you need to replace this line input[name$="eg_payamt_[]"] with ("input:textbox")..

Comment: possible to do like this : $("input:eg_payamt_[]").each(function() { ?

Comment: @user1063526 : no..i dont think so.

Comment: you can use this too: **$("input[type='text'][name='eg_payamt_[]']").each(function(){**

Comment: @user1063526 :  if found "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: textbox" then just change "textbox" to "text" and then try.

Comment: @Chandresh what should I add then so javascript can detect my INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="eg_payamt_[]" Value="' . $amount_dueArr[$record_count] . '" size="10"> and do calculation ?

Comment: it's ok, then how can I display it into this text box ?              <input type="text" name="total" value="<?php echo $amountDueTotal; ?>" />

Comment: @Chandresh how to display the result ( total ammount ) into the next textbox ?

Comment: $("#answer") ?                 <input type="text" name="total" value="$("#answer")" />

Comment: Please check my another answer posted on this question.

Comment: it's not working, because I click one checkbox and I have 5 checkboxes and it shows the total directly not only 1 checkbox total..

Comment: for that you need to do bit of customization in my code dear..its doesn't make a big deal..